# Problem of integrating Wordpress with CakePHP

Tags: wordpress, cakephp

I have an application in which I have implemented a site with CakePHP and also give facility of Wordpress blog.

It is running great on my local server.

But when I am trying to upload it on my staging server, its url doesn't work...

Is anyone else has faced this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide some more details. what kind of setup do you want to achieve? Give the directory structure and some explanation what certain files or setting should do...

Comment: I have installed wordpress in cakephp in following folder :
app/webroot/blog/

Then installed buddypress in wordpress installation.

It is working fine on local server but on live server it is not working and throw an error "missing controller".

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell us what url you are using to access the blog and what the full error message is (which controller does Cake think is missing). It looks to me like you are constructing the link to the blog incorrectly - check in the bottom status bar when you hover over the link.

At a guess - and that's all I can do without more information - you'll have given a url spec in a link element without the leading '/', e.g.

```
echo $html->link('blog','blog'); // relative to current location
```

should be:

```
echo $html->link('blog','/blog'); // relative to webroot
```

Comment: ..and if all else fails, throw in a specific route into `app/config/routes.php`